# unable to get this class working in java on client code - no compilation errors but runtime

Tags: java, string, class, methods, char

I have pasted my code here. below the code I give descriptin of what I am trying to do

```
 import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

//given a string, gives letters counts etc
public class LetterDatabase{
    private String word;
    private int[] charCounts;
    public static final int TOTAL_LETTERS=26;

    //constructor
    public LetterDatabase(String word) {
        this.word=word;
        int[] charCounts= new int[TOTAL_LETTERS];
        //this function fillup charCounts with no of occurances
        //more below
        fillupcharArray();
    }

    /*Returns a count of letters.  
    public int get(char letter) {
    return charCounts[Character.getNumericValue(letter)-10];        
}

/*Sets the count for the given letter to the given value.  
public void set(char letter,int value) {
    int index=Character.getNumericValue(letter-'a');
    charCounts[index]=value;        
 }


/* converts string to Array of chars containing only alphabets
private char[] convertToArray() {
    String str = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
    char[] charArr=new char[str.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            charArr[i] = str.charAt(i);
        }
    return charArr;
}

private void fillupcharArray(){
    char[] charArr=convertToArray();
    for(int i=0;i<charArr.length;i++) {
       for(int j=0;j<26;j++) {
            if (Character.toLowerCase(charArr[i])==Character.toLowerCase((char)('a'+j))) {
           charCounts[j]+=1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

my client code that I used to test is below

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Testdatabase{
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str="my name is Dummy!!!:..,";
    LetterDatabase first= new LetterInventory(str);
    System.out.println(first.get('a'));
    System.out.println(first.set('a'));
    System.out.println(first.get('a'));
    }
 }
```

Explanation: I define a LetterDatabase class which computes the count of letters--only alphabets (type char) in given string. I have a get method, that returns the occurance of particular letter and a set method, that sets the value of letter to a set value.

in my constructor, I am calling a function that fills the array(charCounts), so that I can easily lookup for occurrence of a given char. Firstly my constructor does not work. my class code compiles and my client code above compiles. when I run the clientcode, commenting out the getter and setter calls, i get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at LetterDatabase.fillupcharArray(LetterInventory.java:55)
    at LetterDatabase.<init>(LetterInventory.java:17)
    at Testdatabase.main(hw1test.java:7)
```

I am unable to figure what is going wrong. the fillupcharArray seems to work fine when I test it individually. I am not pasting that here.

secondly, the way I define `get and set` method in my class is not very good. it would be nice if I dont have to use `Character.getNumericValue`

I am open to hear on any other improvements. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are shadowing the array `charCounts` in the constructor of `LetterDatabase`. Replace

```
int[] charCounts = new int[TOTAL_LETTERS];
```

with

```
charCounts = new int[TOTAL_LETTERS];
```

Inside a class method, when a local variable has the same name as an instance variable, the local variable *shadows* the instance variable inside the method block. In this case the local variable `charCounts` is shadowing the instance variable `charCounts`.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

> In computer programming, variable shadowing occurs when a variable declared within a certain scope (decision block, method, or inner class) has the same name as a variable declared in an outer scope

Comment: Have added explanation + wikipedia link (JLS is a bit rubbish here for clear _concise_ expl.)

Answer (score 3):

In your constructor, you've defined a local variable `charCounts`:

```
int[] charCounts= new int[TOTAL_LETTERS];
```

This shadows the *instance variable* `charCounts`, to which I think you meant to assign it.

Assign it to the instance variable `charCounts` like this:

```
charCounts = new int[TOTAL_LETTERS];
```

This means that, in your code, the instance variable `charCounts` remains `null` until you access and a `NullPointerException` results.